# Deploy Fail to using existing address with foundry

Tags: foundry

I encountered this error when i deploy the scripts to the Sepolia.

```
Error: 
script failed: revert: No contract deployed
```

The deploy script is below:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.22;

import {BasicNft} from "../src/BasicNft.sol";
import {Script, console} from "forge-std/Script.sol";
import {Mint1BasicNFT} from "./Interaction.s.sol";

contract DeployBasicNft is Script {
    function run() public returns (BasicNft basicNft) {
        vm.startBroadcast();
        basicNft = new BasicNft();

        vm.stopBroadcast();

        console.log("BasicNft deployed at address: ", address(basicNft));

        if (block.chainid != 31337) {
            console.log("Minting 1 NFT");
            Mint1BasicNFT mint1BasicNFT = new Mint1BasicNFT();
            mint1BasicNFT.run();
        }

        uint256 tokenCounter = basicNft.getTokenCounter();
        string memory token1URI = basicNft.tokenURI(0);

        console.log("Token counter: ", tokenCounter);
        console.log("Token URI: ", token1URI);
    }
}
```

The interaction.s.sol is below:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.22;

import {BasicNft} from "../src/BasicNft.sol";
import {Script} from "forge-std/Script.sol";
import {DevOpsTools} from "../lib/foundry-devops/src/DevOpsTools.sol";

contract Mint1BasicNFT is Script {
    function run() public {
        address mostRecentlyDeployed = DevOpsTools.get_most_recent_deployment(
            "BasicNft",
            block.chainid
        );
        BasicNft basicNft = BasicNft(mostRecentlyDeployed);
        vm.startBroadcast();
        basicNft.mintNft(
            "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmNYSFjNDBidvta5Vgv6xe9GxKcAoBVc8GV1DVTMyeWCGX?filename=branddaojson"
        );
        vm.stopBroadcast();
    }
}
```

Help!

Comment: Pass the private key in `starrBroadcast`. Like this ` vm.startBroadcast(YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY);`

Comment: This video also might help https://youtu.be/AxnvSYxQC5o?si=ak7LZaRKrB2kkY5L

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however the error doesn't come from here, there is some problem with passing the right contract address to the mint1BasicNft script and I have solved this. But still thank you for your recommendation, I will also add the deployer private key when broadcast. @ZartajAfser